# Proving that a given function is continuous in a given set.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Consider the function $q(x) = \frac{1}{2} \| x \|^2$ defined in $C := \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \colon Ax = b \},$ for some matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb R^m$ such that the system in question is feasible.

I aim to prove that such function is continuous.

**My attempt.** By definition, $q$ is continuous if

$$ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta > 0 \colon \, \| x -y\| < \delta \implies | q(x)-q(y)| < \epsilon.$$

Consider arbitrary elements $x,y \in C, \epsilon > 0$ and take $\delta = \sqrt{2\epsilon}.$ Now, suppose that $\| x - y \| < \delta.$ Then,

$$ |q(x)-q(y)| = \frac{1}{2} | \, \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2  | \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \| x - y\|^2 < \frac{1}{2}\delta^2 = \frac{2}{2}\epsilon = \epsilon. $$

Since the elements taken were arbitrary, this proves continuity.

**My concerns after reviewing.** Initially, I tought my attempt might just be right, but after some further thought, I figured that the inequality I used:
$$ | \, \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2 \, | \leqslant \| x-y\|^2$$
doesn't (even) hold for real numbers, let alone for $C$. At the same time, I don't another way to do this.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Your set $C$ and your factor $\frac12$ are irrelevant. I suggest you suppress them from your post, and simply ask for the continuity of $x\mapsto\|x\|^2$ on $\Bbb R^n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write instead
$$ 2|q(x)-q(y)| =  \bigl| \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2  \bigr| =\bigl| \|x\| - \|y\|\bigr|\cdot(\|x\| + \|y\|)\le \|x- y\|\cdot ( \|x-y\| +2 \|y\|)|.
$$
To show that $q$ is continuous at a given $y$ note that if $\|x-y\|<\delta$, then
$$
2|q(x)-q(y)| \le \delta( \delta +2 \|y\|).
$$
Now you just need to take $\delta$ sufficiently small.

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine if you drop the squares. I mean: you seem ready to prove that the map $x\mapsto\|x\|$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^n.$

You certainly know that the map $t\mapsto t^2$ is continuous on $\Bbb R, $ and that the composition of two continuous maps is continuous. (If you don't, better concentrate on proving these two basic facts than solving your exercise.)

So, you have won.

Comment: That's a cool approach - a good way to avoid a direct approach. Thanks for your help.